# Complex analysis knowledge that required to understand material in Riemann Surface

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, advice

I have taken a course on complex analysis in university, at that time the instructor chose the book "Complex Analysis" by Serge Lang. Now I am participating a cemina on Riemann Surfaces which truly based on the book Lecture on Riemann surfaces by Forster. With my simple background on complex analysis, I almost did not understand the material in lecture 2 : Elementary properties of holomorphic mappings (that I do not found in the book of Lang).

So, my question is : Which book on complex analysis should I read in preparing for that cemina?  Please help me. Thanks

**Edit**: What I want to say is : With my background on complex analysis, I could not understand the proofs of some theorems, corollaries,... in section 2 of the book of Forster. I really want to know which book I should read to understand them. The section 1 does not use much complex analysis, so it is not my problem now.

Comment: Lang's book should be perfectly fine background. Don't forget the first section of Forster's book, too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use Bak & Newman's "Complex Analysis" for an introduction to the basics. The book by Forster is a good one; personally I loved Farkas & Kra's "Riemann Surfaces". It contains the complex analysis which is used in the book and the section on theta functions is simply great. Miranda's "Algebraic curves and Riemann Surfaces" is a nice one, too.

Comment: Would you say that bak & Newman is a good pre/core-req for Farkas kra. Are there any others that would be a good supplement to it to help understand the material?